# Running Command via Java ProccesBuilder Different to Running the same in the Shell

Tags: java, command, processbuilder

I'm tearing my hair out trying to work out why the command I'm executing via Java using a ProcessBuilder & Process is not working. I run the "same" command at the Windows command line and it works as expected. It must be that they're not the same but I can't for the life of me work out why.

The command is this:

```
ccm start -nogui -m -q -n ccm_admin -r developer -d /path/to/db/databasename -s http://hostname:8400 -pw Passw0rd789$
```

The output is should be a single line string that I need to grab and set as an environment variable (hence the v. basic use of the `BufferedReader`).

My Java code, which when it runs the command gets an application error, looks like this with entry point being `startCCMAndGetCCMAddress()`:

```
private static String ccmAddress = "";

private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/path/to/db/databasename";
private static final String SYNERGY_URL = "http://hostname:8400";

private static final String USERNAME = "ccm_admin";
private static final String PASSWORD = "Passw0rd789$";
private static final String USER_ROLE = "developer";


public static List<String> getCCMStartCommand() {
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();

    command.add("cmd.exe");
    command.add("/C");

    command.add("ccm");
    command.add("start");
    command.add("-nogui");
    command.add("-m");
    command.add("-q");
    command.add("-n "+USERNAME);
    command.add("-r "+USER_ROLE);
    command.add("-d "+DATABASE_PATH);
    command.add("-s "+SYNERGY_URL);
    command.add("-pw "+PASSWORD);

    return command;
}

private static String startCCMAndGetCCMAddress() throws IOException, CCMCommandException {
    int processExitValue = 0;

    List<String> command = getCCMStartCommand();

    System.err.println("Will run: "+command);

    ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process proc = procBuilder.start();
    BufferedReader outputBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        processExitValue = proc.exitValue();
    }

    String outputLine = outputBr.readLine();
    outputBr.close();

    if (processExitValue != 0) {
        throw new CCMCommandException("Command failed with output: " + outputLine);
    }

    if (outputLine == null) {
        throw new CCMCommandException("Command returned zero but there was no output");
    }

    return outputLine;

}
```

The output of the `System.err.println(...)` is:

```
Will run: [cmd.exe, /C, ccm, start, -nogui, -m, -q, -n ccm_admin, -r developer, -d /path/to/db/databasename, -s http://hostname:8400, -pw Passw0rd789$]
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you split each option/value as separate entries in the `command` list? For example add "-n" and "USERNAME" as separate (subsequent) entries?

Comment: can you show us the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide each argument *separately*, and without leading/trailing spaces, rather than concatenating select ones e.g "-pw PASSWORD". That way you'll invoke the process with the correct argument set (as it would see from the command line)

Comment: <slaps forehead> Doh! Should have known that. Thanks.